# libfontconfig on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, package, candidate

As I want to use grafana on a server running ubuntu 14.04 I need to install libfontconfig from libfontconfig1, but somehow there's no installation candidate. If I run sudo apt-get install libfontconfig, I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Package libfontconfig is a virtual package provided by:
  libfontconfig1 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2 [Not candidate version]
```

E: Package 'libfontconfig' has no installation candidate

Is there no candidate for ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4):

try `apt-get install libfontconfig1`